# How to match absolute value using regex

Tags: c++, regex

I am having trouble with absolute value in regex in C++. This is what I have as the pattern:

```
std::tr1::regex loadAbsNM("load -|M\\((\\d+)\\)|");    // load -|M(x)|
```

I am trying to use `std::tr1::regex_match( IR, result, loadNM )` to match. But it is not matching anything, even though it should be.

I'm using Visual Stuido 2010 compilier

**shortened version of program** (included above is iostream and regex)

```
int main()
{

 std::string IR = "load -|M(x)|";

 std::smatch result;
 std::tr1::regex loadAbsNM("load -|M\\((\\d+)\\)|");
 if( std::tr1::regex_match( IR , result, loadAbsNM ) )
 {
  int x = 2;
  std::cout << "matched!" << std::endl;
 }
 else
 {
  std::cout << "!UNABLE TO DECODE INSTRUCTION!" << std::endl;
 }
}
```

**output produced**

!UNABLE TO DECODE INSTRUCTION!

Comment: Show a complete, minimal program that compiles and runs and shows the problem.

Comment: What compiler are you using ?

Comment: Are you using gcc? If so, `regex` implementation is only available in (as of now unreleased) gcc-4.9. If you're using some other compiler, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Praetorian - Have to love yet another acronym. (I like it)

Comment: @ryyker That one's actually [quite common](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=sscce+site:stackoverflow.com) around here :)

Comment: Check your input or handle potential garbage in the regex, `regex_match` return true only if the whole string matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that from your code, you're not going to have a match. The letter `x` won't match the regex `\d+`.

Also, I'm not too sure whether you need a backslash in front of the pipe character. As you may know, pipe (`|`) is used to separate possible entries: `(a|b)` means a or b.

Finally, since their is a pipe at the end, the expression matches the empty string which is often a bad idea.

I would suggest something like this:

```
"load -\\|M\\((\\d+)\\)\\|"
```

But that won't match:

```
"load -|M(x)|"
```

You'd need to use a number instead of 'x' as in:

```
"load -|M(123)|"
```

Comment: @user3010769: Welcome to SO! Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page any time soon. For now, please read [How does "accepting an answer work?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).